# How does `xargs` work on the filenames provided by `find`, which may cause problems?

Tags: xargs

From findutils' manual about `xargs`

> In many applications, if xargs botches processing a file because its
>   name contains special characters, some data might be lost.
>
> However, here is an extreme example of the problems that using
>   blank-delimited names can cause. If the following command is run daily
>   from cron, then any user can remove any file on the system:
>
> ```
> find / -name ’#*’ -atime +7 -print | xargs rm
> ```
>
> For example, you could do something like this:
>
> ```
> eg$ echo > ’#
> vmunix’
> ```
>
> and then cron **would delete /vmunix**, if it ran xargs with / as its
>   current directory.
>
> To **delete other files**, for example /u/joeuser/.plan, you could do
>   this:
>
> ```
> eg$ mkdir ’#
> ’
> eg$ cd ’#
> ’
> eg$ mkdir u u/joeuser u/joeuser/.plan’
> ’
> eg$ echo > u/joeuser/.plan’
> /#foo’
> eg$ cd ..
> eg$ find . -name ’#*’ -print | xargs echo
> ./# ./# /u/joeuser/.plan /#foo
> ```

In the above examples, how does `xargs` work on the filenames provided by `find`, and how can that delete files?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in how `xargs` reads the input and passes it onto the command.

We can see this pretty easily with `rm -i`

```
$ touch a 'b c' 'd
> e'
$ find -type f | cat
./d
e
./b c
./a
$ find -type f | xargs rm -i
rm: cannot remove './d': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'e': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove './b': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'c': No such file or directory
rm: remove regular empty file './a'? $
```

Note that we try to remove 5 files; `./a`, `./b`, `c`, `./d`, and `e`

So both the space and the newline in the filename causes two arguments to be passed to the command.

The standard solution is to use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`

```
$ find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -i
rm: cannot remove '.': Is a directory
rm: remove regular empty file './d\ne'? 
rm: remove regular empty file './b c'? 
rm: remove regular empty file './a'? $
```

Now the NUL character (which can't be part of a filename) is used as the separator and the whitespace isn't significant.

Comment: `-print0` xand `xargs -0` are not standard. `find . -type f -exec rm -i {} +` is standard (and doesn't have the xargs issue that `rm -i` could read the answer to its prompts from the pipe from `find` with some `xargs` implementations). Note that with GNU `xargs`, you'd need `xargs -r0` for the equivalent of that `-exec {} +`.

Comment: I was just using `rm -i` to highlight how `xargs` was splitting stuff up, and so showing how `rm` could delete unexpected files as a result.  As you point out, the `-i` doesn't work properly because of the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The other half of the question, is what to do about it.
The answer to this is to use `\0` delimiting instead of white space delimiting (`-0` in not allowed in a file-name, it is the only character that is not allowed. `/` is part of a filename but has a special purpose).

To do this change the code as follows.

`find … -print0 | xargs -0 …`